# Text File Parsing - Java Bean Instantiation with mwe2 (Xtext)

Tags: java, parsing, xtext, mwe

I have text files to be parsed (i.e., convert to Java Bean Instances),

Formed the required XText grammar.

**My XText Grammar:**

```
grammar org.eclipse.xtext.example.Domainmodel with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate domainmodel "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/example/Domainmodel"

Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name =ID '!' ;
```

Able to generate the Greeting and Model Java Bean Classes, By running **" Generate XText Artifacts "**  Generated Bean classes are given below

**Greeting.java**

```
package org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel;

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;

public interface Greeting extends EObject
{
  String getName();
  void setName(String value);

}
```

**Model.java**

```
package org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;

public interface Model extends EObject
{
  EList<Greeting> getGreetings();
}
```

**GenerateDomainmodel.mwe2** generated.

Able to generate Resource using the **.genmodel**, as given in the below **Main (Partial)** class

```
package org.eclipse.xtext.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

import org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenModel;
import org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenModelPackage;
import org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenPackage;
import org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenModelImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.TreeIterator;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.EcoreResourceFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.mwe2.Mwe2Package;
import org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.IWorkflow;
import org.eclipse.xtext.AbstractElement;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.DomainmodelFactory;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Greeting;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Model;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.impl.DomainmodelFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.impl.DomainmodelPackageImpl;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.impl.GreetingImpl;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        new DomainmodelStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSetImpl();
        rs.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("genmodel", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

        EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.put(GenModelPackage.eNS_URI, GenModelPackage.eINSTANCE);

        File f = new File("/data/TASKS/4. 2016-2017_PS1/XTEXT/ECLIPSE WORKSPACE 1/org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel/model/generated/Domainmodel.genmodel");
        System.out.println(f.canRead());
        Resource resource = rs.getResource(URI.createURI(f.toURI().toString()), true);
    }
}
```

Having done all this, How to generate the **Greeting** class instances using the below
**text input file**.

```
Hello Ramasamy !
Hello Govinda Govinda !
Hello Kuppusamy !
Hello Karuppusamy !
```

I am in need of Model Instance, which contains 4 No. of Greeting Instances with the following values as a name.

1. Greeting instance1 -> name  ( " Ramasamy " )
2. Greeting instance1 -> name  ( " Govinda Govinda " )
3. Greeting instance1 -> name  ( " Kuppusamy " )
4. Greeting instance1 -> name  ( " Karuppusamy " )

My Main program has to generate the Greeting instances using the above text input file, Can somebody help me out on this

Or is there any other way to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for such a main

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Greeting;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Model;

import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Injector i = new MyDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = i.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);
        Resource r = rs.getResource(URI.createFileURI("./test.mydsl"), true);
        r.load(null);
        Model m = (Model) r.getContents().get(0);
        for (Greeting g : m.getGreetings()) {
            System.out.println(g.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

updated to your code it would look like

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.DomainmodelStandaloneSetup;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Greeting;
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Model;

import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Injector i = new DomainmodelStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = i.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);
        Resource r = rs.getResource(URI.createFileURI("./src/mydsl.dmodel"), true);
        r.load(null);
        Model m = (Model) r.getContents().get(0);
        for (Greeting g : m.getGreetings()) {
            System.out.println(g.getNamee());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, getting following exception while getting Model Instance                                                                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.impl.GenModelImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.Model
 at org.eclipse.xtext.example.MainStack001.main(MainStack001.java:75)

Comment: can u help on this

Comment: no i need more context/a reproducible example for that

Comment: Can u refer Main method in my question, from there I created resource instance and use your following statements,  r.load(null);
        Model m = (Model) r.getContents().get(0);
        for (Greeting g : m.getGreetings()) {
            System.out.println(g.getName());
        }

Comment: In this while getting Model instance from r getting exception

Comment: as i said: a git repo or something like that would help me to reproduce

Comment: Hi, https://github.com/gopaltirupur/xtextTextToJavaBeanParsing.git         uploaded the project here, Having the Main class at org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel - Thanks

Comment: sorry the main makes no sense. which file do you want to read?

Comment: Hello Ramasamy !
Hello Govinda Govinda !
Hello Kuppusamy !
Hello Karuppusamy !

Comment: but where is that file? i find zero in the project.

Comment: can u help me with the path where i should keep this file in the project

Comment: dont understand. you can read your mydsl file from anywhere in the filesystem

Comment: pushed mydsl file

Comment: sure did not receive anything

Comment: files should be call `mydsl.dmodel`

Comment: pushed the change